# How to open an .png type image in Linux terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, images, xdg-open

I just can't find the command to display a *.png image! I tried `xdg-open` command but it failed:

```
[student@seqpapl1 Images]$ xdg-open adapter_content.png 
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'adapter_content.png'
```

I am currently running ubuntu linux on the server.

Comment: What terminal program are you using?  On what sort of machine? In what environment?  it's possible you could just install something like `imgcat` depending on the answers to these questions.

Comment: Are you remoting in to the server? Do you have an xterm session running?

Comment: Yes, I am remoting in to the server.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `mimeopen -d` to set the default application:

```
mimeopen -d image.png
```

sample output:

```
Please choose a default application for files of type image/png
1) ImageMagick (color depth=q16)  (display-im6.q16)
2) GNU Image Manipulation Program  (gimp)
3) Feh (feh)
```

Select your default application , next time you will be able to use:

```
mimeopen image.png
```

or:

```
xdg-open image.png
```

Answer (score 2):

or you can also use

`gio open image.png`

Comment: Useful command: works for any file type. 
The command automatically chooses the default app based on the file type and opens the file with that default app.